# IAR Pre-Build batch file python call not working

Tags: batch-file, embedded, msp430, iar, pre-build-event

I'm trying to setup a script to increment a build number inside a version file in IAR EW430.  I've got the python script and the batch file working from the command line, but when I run it on the IAR IDE, the build number doesn't increment.

In the IAR Project, I have Options > Build Actions > Pre-build command line set to:

```
$PROJ_DIR$\pre-build.bat "$PROJ_DIR$"
```

The batch file pre-build.bat is:

```
@echo off
set arg1=%1
python VersionInc.py %arg1%
echo on
```

Right now, arg1 is just the path to the "version.h" file that python manipulates, and is the same path as the project for these tests.

When I recompile in IAR, the build message reports "Performing Pre-Build Action" and shows the correct path and argument being sent and I see a command window pop up for a short time, but the file doesn't get manipulated.  What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assume which directory you are executing Python in. You need to specify the directory where your script is located.

```
pushd {path to VersionInc.py directory}
python VersionInc.py %arg1%
popd
```

or alternatively, if your script can be executed from any directory:

```
python {path to VersionInc.py directory}\VersionInc.py %arg1%
```